# How many integers $n$ are there such that $1 \le n \le 1000$ and the highest common factor of $n$ and $36$ is $1$.

Tags: integers

I am having hard time understanding the questions and I can't think of any way to solve it, it's a question from a competitive test.

Comment: Well, for a start you can start by considering all the prime numbers from 1 to 100. Then proceed to find all composite number from 1 to 100 s.t. the hcf with 36 is 1. A useful hint is to consider the prime factorization of 36 = 2^2 × 3^2.

Comment: Ok I'll try. Thanks but sorry it's 1000 actually.

Comment: The usual method will still hold. More explicitly, since 36 = 2^2 × 3^2, the numbers you want to find must not contain 2 or 3 in its prime factorization. In other words it may contain other primes such as 5,7, 11,etc... One example is 5^2 × 7 = 175. Can you take it from here?

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the prime factors of $36$ are $2$ and $3$, the integers coprime to $36$ are of the form $6k+1$ and $6k+5$.  The largest $6k+1$ that is less than $1000$ is $997$.  How many $6k+1$s are there?  Then for $6k+5 \ldots$

Comment: I like this way than any other +1

Comment: This is really good method thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

$36 = 2^2\times 3^2$. Any number which is divisible by neither $2$ nor $3$ satisfies the property in question. There are $50$ numbers divisible by $2$, and $33$ numbers divisible by $3$. The numbers divisible by $6$ ($16$of them) are counted twice, so the result is $100 - 50 - 33 + 16 = 33$